# Rails 5, Capistrano 3 how to clear cache after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I want to execute the cap equivalent of

```
Rails.cache.clear
```

after deploy, but cannot get it to work.  Here's my attempt in the deploy.rb file

```
namespace :deploy do
    after :restart, :clear_cache do
        on release_roles(fetch(:assets_roles)) do
            within release_path do
                with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
                    Rails.cache.clear
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@hostname.com  uninitialized constant Rails
```

If not this, what?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

update:

This is the right syntax:

```
namespace :deploy do
    task :clear_cache do
        on roles(:app) do |host|
            with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
                within current_path do
                    execute :rake, "cache:clear"
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You could use [this](https://github.com/piotr-kedziak/capistrano-cache) gem. And add the line `set :clear_cache_after_deploy, true` in deploy.rb, and the cache will be cleared after every deployment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest that you should create a rake task for clearing cache and invoke them using capistrano hooks. For example:

**lib/tasks/cache.rb**

```
namespace :cache do
  desc 'clear rails cache'
  task clear: :environment do
    Rails.cache.clear
  end
end
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
namespace :cache do
  task :clear do
    on roles(:app) do |host|
      with rails_env: fetch(:rails_env) do
        within current_path do
          execute :bundle, :exec, "rake cache:clear"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:update', 'cache:clear'
```

Comment: The syntax has changed a little, but the spirit of this is correct, i'll post the right answer in my question.

Comment: @user1130176 what has changed ?

Comment: @CyrilDuchon-Doris thanks for the nudge, i've updated the question to show the correct syntax